# How to do an update in DynamoDb

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to do an `Update` in DynamoDb for a `TransactWriteItem`. That is an item is already present in the table and I would like to replace its value with something else.

The problem that I have is that the apparently reasonable code does not work:

```
let request = Update::builder()
   .table_name("MyBeautifulTable")
   .key("item_key", AttributeValue::B(Blob::new(...)))
   .expression_attribute_value("item_value", AttributeValue::B(Blob::new(...)))
   .update_expression("SET item_key = item_value")
   .build()
```

Results in the following error: `ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \"item_value\"`.

Comment: It almost looks like your key has quotes in it. Is `Blob` the correct kind of value to use here?

Comment: I had a mistake in my code, I was using `:value` instead of `item_value`. Now is my intent.

Answer (score 2):

I provided an update your code, notice I changed the UpdateExpression, for 2 reasons.

1. You weren't using the `:value` variable.
2. I changed `item_key` because you cannot change the key of an item. If you wish to change an items key you need to remove the existing item and add a new one.

```
 request = Update::builder()
   .table_name("MyBeautifulTable")
   .key("item_key", AttributeValue::B(Blob::new(...)))
   .expression_attribute_values(":value", AttributeValue::B(Blob::new(...)))
   .update_expression("SET item_attrib = :value")
   .build()
```

Have a look at our examples [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/rust/working_with_items/src/update-item/main.rs) they should help you with your syntax.

Comment: What is `item_attrib` here?

Comment: It's a made up attribute to show how to update an attribute. You cannot change a keys value.